# Is there a high-load chat software / script out there?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql, chat

We're in development of a website and we're looking into other options than just developing a chat engine ourselves.

We've looked at CometChat and ArrowChat. Which look and seem to be great except that it uses PHP/MySQL. They offer to host your chat server which can handle 100,000+ but honestly we'd like to be hosting it on our own servers and handle way more than that.

Know of any alternatives? We're looking for that Meebo/Facebook/CometChat/ArrowChat look and style but it needs to be fully customizable.

Comment: Are you looking for server software or client software?

Comment: Client software I believe.

Comment: Then use whatever client software you want... client software only handles one client at a time, so there's no need to "scale".

Answer (score 2):

Use a XMPP server like [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) to handle the chat sessions. Then you can write your own XMPP client (e.g. in jQuery or wherever you want to run the client on) or check out [this nice thread with several web-based XMPP clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687612/xmpp-web-client).